# Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vercel

I am trying to create a service to convert an SVG to a PNG using the [svg2img](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg2img) package. I have it working locally using `vercel dev`, however when I try to deploy to vercel I always get this error:

```
2021-09-27T01:11:56.532Z    e3a35069-8a51-4e1d-81b9-110e1b17e2be    ERROR   Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /var/task/api/node_modules/canvg/lib/index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /var/task/api/node_modules/canvg/lib/index.js from /var/task/api/node_modules/svg2img/index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename /var/task/api/node_modules/canvg/lib/index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /var/task/api/node_modules/canvg/package.json.
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/api/node_modules/svg2img/index.js:1:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
RequestId: e3a35069-8a51-4e1d-81b9-110e1b17e2be Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

Here is what my code looks like:

```js
import svg2img from 'svg2img';

export default function(req, res) {
  const url = req.query.url;
  const width = req.query.width;
  const height = req.query.height;
  const size = Math.min(width, height);
  svg2img(url, {width: size, height: size, preserveAspectRatio: true},
    function(error, buffer) {
      if (buffer) {
        res.send(buffer);
      }
  });
};
```

Here is the package.json

```json
{
  "name": "svg2png",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "convert svgs to pngs",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "svg2img": "^0.9.3"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ that's the entire  error, or did you not paste the whole error? Because any more version of Node (LTS 14 or current 16) can work with modules just fine, provided you remembered to mark your project as using modern ES modules in `package.json`, by stating `"type": "module"`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans added the full error message

Comment: And did you mark your project as a modern module-based codebase in your own `package.json`? Because it looks like you didn't, and you [absolutely have to](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) if you want to use `import` statements. (edit: nice edit on your post, where suddenly your package.json has a "type" value. Does it actually? If so: do you even still have this problem?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans even with this in my package.json file I still am getting an error. Trying to decipher the error, I wonder if the problem is that svg2img is not using modules to import canvas?

Comment: Node doesn't care as long as _each_ dependency is properly typed. You can `import` from a non-module library just fine, and you can `require` from a moduled dependecy. So: which version of Node are you using?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Project is set to 14.x on Vercel

Comment: I will never continue comments in chat. The point of SO is that your post stands on its own, no comments or chat required.

Comment: That said: your code uses the modern ES module `import`, but then tries to export using the legacy CJS `module.exports` construct. Obviously, don't do that: either use the legacy `require` and `modules.export`, or use `import` and `export`.

Comment: Good point, I'd never seen the chat before. Thank you for the help! I switched to `export default function(req, res) {` but am still getting the same error: `2021-09-27T02:28:53.599Z 12aec7cc-fafe-42c3-b0e8-a7579abfcfbd ERROR Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /var/task/api/node_modules/canvg/lib/index.js`

Answer (score 0):

You can try lowering the version of `svg2img` to one that doesn't use `3.0.8` of `canvg` which uses [`"type": "module"`](https://github.com/canvg/canvg/blob/master/package.json#L26) in their `package.json`. `svg2img` uses [`require('canvg')`](https://github.com/fuzhenn/node-svg2img/blob/master/index.js#L1) which causes the error because it is trying to use commonjs in an esm context.

See [this](https://github.com/fuzhenn/node-svg2img/issues/59) issue.

Comment: How can I find a version of svg2img that uses 3.0.8?

Comment: Use the dropdown when you click on the branch for the `svg2img` repo on github. There is a "Tags" tab that allows you to select releases. Looks like `v0.9.2` of `svg2img` uses [`3.0.6` of `canvg`](https://github.com/fuzhenn/node-svg2img/blob/v0.9.2/package-lock.json#L228).

Comment: thank you, however still getting the same error... changed to `"svg2img": "^0.9.2"` but still getting `ERROR Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /var/task/api/node_modules/canvg/lib/index.js`

Comment: You have to get `canvg` to resolve to a lower version. If you use `yarn` you could try  `resolutions`. v3.0.7 does not seem to include `type: module` in the [package.json](https://github.com/canvg/canvg/blob/v3.0.7/package.json).

Comment: Is there a way I can specify to not use modules in my package?

Comment: Yes but the issue is with your dependency on `svg2img`  which only supports commonjs usage of `canvg`, which itself is an es module. The issue I linked to in the answer suggests an alternative to `svg2img`, you can try that. Or just remove `type: module` from your package.json and convert all your modules to commonjs.